# Displaying custom tooltip over AppWindow

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to add custom tooltips into my Chrome packaged app. I've tried Twitter's Bootstrap and jquery.tipsy which works fine, though I don't seem to be able to get the behavior I want.

The problem is that I have a quite tiny window and therefore I would like tooltip to stretch over the AppWindow's border.

The default tooltip using HTML element's title attribute (e.g. `<button title="My Tooltip text">Click!</button>`) does exactly that, so I wonder whether it is possible to style the tooltip privided by title attribute or to make a plug-in tooltip to float over the window's bounds?

Comment: Nope. But you can create another window with frame:none, and make that your tooltip.

Comment: @sowbug That's unfortunate. Using another window may work, though as far as I'm aware, AppWindow can't be made transparent, so I can't do speech bubble type of tooltip.